# How to declare parameters (variables) in a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

Given a spark view named `SomeContainer.spark` that uses a partial view this way:

```
<SomeContent param1 = "Model.SomeValue"/>
```

and given a partial view named `SomeContent.spark` that uses the parameter this way:

```
<div>${param1}</div>
```

How can I modify `SomeContent.spark` to declare param1 upfront. I want to do that for two reasons:

- Readability: readers will know what the partial view depends on
- To get intellisence for param1 in Visual Studio

I tried to simply declare the same `<var>` in SomeContent.spark but it fails at runtime indicating that that variable already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer from the Spark group. In the partial you can declare a variable using the `<default/>` element:

```
<default param1="new List<string>()" type="List[[string]]"/>
```

Not only does it declare the parameter (with the advantages mentioned in my question) but it also gives it a default value which can be used to prevent the partial form getting a NullReferenceException...